# How to extract the text within the element using Selenium WebDriver and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Grab the text of the specified area.

Website: https://www.kobo.com/tw/zh/ebook/NXUCYsE9cD6OWhvtdTqQQQ.

Image:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/qK1uA9L]

Code:

```
BookTitle = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class="title product-field"]')
BookTitle[0].getWindowHandle()
```

HTML:

```
<span translate="no">大塊文化</span>
```

Comment: Your selector has nothing to do with the element, generally you could right click the element on dev tool to copy  selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text **大塊文化** from the specified area you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.kobo.com/tw/zh/ebook/NXUCYsE9cD6OWhvtdTqQQQ')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='電子書詳細資料']//following::ul[1]//li/a[@class='description-anchor']/span"))).text)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  大塊文化
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing in wrong way :

`BookTitle[0].getWindowHandle()` not suppose to do anything here

Simply try :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='description-anchor']>span").text
```

Comment: `a[class='description-anchor']` -> `a.description-anchor` perhaps more canonical

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://www.kobo.com/tw/zh/ebook/NXUCYsE9cD6OWhvtdTqQQQ")
element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a.description-anchor span[translate="no"]')))
print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[translate="no"]')`

CSS Selectors should be faster than XPath

**EDIT** Edited per DebanjanB comment - thank you

Comment: Did you test your answer before publishing it? Does your code compiles?? Is your solution _Python_ based as per OP's requirement???

Comment: My apologies reagarding the Python solution, I missed the tag

**Edited** to a Python version a yes, it does compile for me

Comment: I'm using this very syntax in my work....
However, I'm confused, other answers suggest very similar if not the same solution, how could my answer have compilation errors and theirs not

Comment: You are missing the _single quotes_ i.e. **`'...'`** around the _selector_ and it should have been `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[translate="no"]')`

Comment: Edited and I apologize for this dumb mistake